# Face recognition by Eigenfaces on Open CV from python gives zero matrix

Tags: python, opencv

I am using Open CV 2.4.6 on ubuntu 12.04.
I got face recognition through EigenFaces working on cpp .

I tried using opencv python, which is exactly the same. But gives me zero matrix as output prediction. Even if my test image is same as the trained one, output is zero.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np


if __name__=='__main__':
    print "Face matching"
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
            print "USAGE: matchfaces.py img1 img2"
            sys.exit()
    X= []
    x1 = []
    print sys.argv[2]
    im1 = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1],cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    im2 = cv2.imread(sys.argv[2],cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    model = cv2.createEigenFaceRecognizer()

    X.append(np.asarray(im1, dtype=np.uint8))
    X.append(np.asarray(im1, dtype=np.uint8))
    x1.append(0)
    x1.append(0)
    xlabels = np.asarray(x1, dtype=np.int32)
    model.train(X,xlabels)
    print model
    [p_label, p_confidence] = model.predict(np.asarray(im2, dtype=np.uint8))
    print "Done"
    print p_label, p_confidence
    print model.getMat("eigenvalues")
```

Can anyone let me know any good tutorials or blogs on opencv with python.

Thanks,
saiyan

Comment: your label array only contains zeros, so that's what you get.

Comment: No, the eigen value and confidence should be something instead of zero right.

Comment: honestly, use better test data. you only have 2 images, and both the same. what do you think, their eigenvalues should be ?

Comment: Thanks berak, yeah with a bigger data set i got the results.

Comment: Thanks berak, yeah with a bigger data set i got the results. yes  distance wud be zero for same images.Actually i wanted to find the similarity between two facial images. I can get a distance among two images with features extracted. But can you suggest me something which can be better than that.

Comment: sorry, i did not understand that. the facerecognition, as it is now, gives you the distance and id of the closest item in the database. are you looking for one-shot-similarity ?

Comment: yes i dont want to compare with a database. i want to compare only the two images

Comment: the most simple form would be the l2 norm, like : `distance = cv2.norm(im1,im2,cv2.NORM_L2)`

Comment: yes may be a feature extraction and norm wud enhance. ok thanks a lot